# Errors after moving DB from server

Tags: sql-server, hyper-v, corruption

I am moving a database (MS SQL Server) from a server to a new one (virtual machine).

Running CHECKDB on the original server I get no errors, the DB is OK.
After moving the DB to the new server and running CHECKDB I get 42 consistency errors.

I'm moving the DB (mdf and ldf files) from LAN.
This is only happening with this DB. Others moved ok.

I've tried passing it many times and it always get corrupted. I already tried restore a backup from the original server, but still the DB keeps with errors.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try compressing the files (even just with `tar`) to see if that gets the files over okay.

Comment: When uncompressing I get an Error 0x80004005. I ran chksk on the virtual machine HDD and windows says the disk is OK - no errors. Is the problem in network and the file is corrupted moving within the LAN?

Comment: I'm thinking so. You can try using an md5 sum generator http://www.winmd5.com/ on both sides to see if the file's coming through properly.

Comment: The MD5 did not matched on the mdf file. The log file is ok. Is there any way of copying the file and verify the output? Maybe robocopy can be more reliable?

Comment: I finally managed to put the file on the VM without corrupting it. Instead of copying it directly between the original and destination server, I first copied the DB to another machine and from it to the VM. It's odd, but at least with this process I get a valid MD5 checksum.